# z-index property of @media print css is not applying while printing the page

Tags: css

[Result expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOkH7.png)

[Actual O/P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAryy.png)

Here are my css classes:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
.h6 {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.line-center {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.h6:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
    z-index: -1;
}
}
.h6 {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.line-center {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.h6:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
    z-index: -1;
}

<style>
<head>
<body>
<h6 class="h6"><span class="line-center">Hello StackOverflow</span></h6>
</body>
</html>
```

I have Print button on my page, which executes `window.print()`. So onclick of print button I want the same output which I am getting on page but while printing, the page format is not coming as expected, please click on the hyperlinks for screenshots of output I am getting.

Comment: which css class are you applying on which tag?

Comment: Please refer this line: <h6 class="h6"><span class="line-center">Hello StackOverflow</span></h6> @RichaGarg

Comment: It's resolved now. :)

Comment: You can post it as an answer and accept it :)